# Peano axioms: $∀y∀x(x×y = y×x)$, using induction in $y$

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms, natural-deduction

Considering a first order logic language for arithmetic and the Peano's axioms (PA) for the number theory get natural deduction (with Fitch notation) for the following $\psi$ formulas (i.e. PA $⊢ \psi$).

Peano's axioms:

1. $∀x(x+1 \neq 0)$
2. $∀x∀y(x+1 = y+1 → x = y)$
3. $0+1 = 1$
4. $∀x(x+0 = x)$
5. $∀x∀y(x+(y+1) = (x+y)+1)$
6. $∀x(x×0 = 0)$
7. $∀x∀y(x×(y+1) = (x×y)+x)$
8. (principle of induction) $(\varphi[0/x] ∧ ∀x(\varphi → \varphi[x+1/x])) → ∀x$ $\varphi$

How to use Axiom 8: being $∀x$ $\varphi$ what you want to deduct, you should deduct $\varphi([0/x])$ first and then $∀x(\varphi → \varphi[x+1/x])$ (and using axiom 8 and modus ponens you get what you want).

Comment: How far have you gotten? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't want anyone to do the exercice I just need some help on how I'm supposed to solve it that would already help a lot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with first-order PA, but don't you also need some kind of "is a number" predicate if not a set $N$ in your axioms? Don't you need something like: If $x$ and $y$ are numbers, then so is $x+y$?

Comment: My teacher said I need to use first order logic for arithmetic in order to solve the problem. Suppose that the problem is: $∀x$ $0+x=x$. She solves it like this: [image](https://i.gyazo.com/ce6af840fb1da6dbea14c31b13a6db35.png). Basically in this problem I need to start by doing the base case which is $x×0 = 0×x$ and then get to $x×(y+1) = (y+1)×x$, but I'm having a hard time trying to make the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

You have to follow the "instructions" on how to use Ax.8 [the *Induction axiom*].

The first step is to find the correct formula $\varphi(x)$ to which apply the axiom; the natural choice is to consider :

> $\varphi(x) := \forall y \ (x \times y = y \times x)$.

If so, $\varphi(0)$ will be : $\forall y \ (0 \times y = y \times 0)$ and thus the induction proof will be organized with :

*(i)* *basis* - prove that :

> $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall y \ (0 \times y = y \times 0)$

i.e. $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \varphi(0)$;

*(ii)* *induction step* - prove that :

> $ \forall y \ (x \times y = y \times x) \to \forall y \ ((x+1) \times y = y \times (x+1))$

i.e. $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall x \ [\varphi(x) \to \varphi(x+1)]$.

Finally, with *(i)* and *(ii)* use Ax.8 and $\to$-elim [i.e. *modus ponens*] twice to conclude with :

> > $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall x \ \varphi$.

Comment: At step $i$ and $ii$ shouldn't it be $PA⊢∀y (x×0=0×x)$ and $∀y (x×y=y×x)→∀y (x×(y+1)=×(y+1)×x)$ respectively since it's "using induction in $y$"?

Comment: I got to $∀x$ $x×(u+1) = (x×u)+1$. How can I get to $∀x$ $x×(u+1) = (u+1)×x$?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - do you have $∀x [x \times (u+1)=(x \times u)+1]$ ? How ? $3 \times (2+1)=9 \ne (3 \times 2)+1=7$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $∀x ×(u+1)=(x×u)+x$.

Comment: @JoãoSilva - by induction hyp you have : $x \times u=u \times x$; thus : $x \times (u+1) = (x \times u)+x = (u \times x) +x$. To proceed, you have to prove separately that : $(u+1) \times x = (u \times x)+x$.